# Try with resources JDBC queries

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working through a swing tutorial that interacts with a database using JDBC.  The tutorial uses a different approach than what I have seen in the past when interacting with databases.

Previously, one method was used for the update or query.  A try with resources block was used to create a connection object and statements, the query was executed and the connection closed automatically afterwards.  I believed this was the correct way.

In this swing tutorial, there is a method that creates the connection, a method to perform the query and a method to close the connection.  As I see it, the connection to the database is being kept open for the duration of the application life-cycle.  Is this common practice?  This is a tutorial from 2013 so I thought it may just be outdated.

I am very new to JDBC an would like to know what the recommended approach is now.

Thanks

Apologies if my question is ambiguous.  What I was mostly concerned with was whether I should open and close a connection for each operation or just keep the connection open as long as my application was running.

Is there a benefit to separating connect and disconnect to their own methods?

Comment: Search for a recent tutorial.

Comment: For a stand-alone desktop application keeping the connection open is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks. To both of you.

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A try-with-resources is necessary if there are multiple users (threads) competing for the resource, such as in a multi-user web application. In these cases the `close()` won't actually close the connection, it will just return it to the pool so it's available for other threads to check out.

If you're creating a single user Swing application, it's not harmful to keep a `Connection` open for a longer time as you're the only one using it.

Comment: Thanks.  Marking as answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Kayaman Try-with-resource does not have any relation with multithreading

Comment: @talex That's not at all what I was saying. I was saying that if you're dealing with a resource that's shared by multiple users (such as threads in a web application), you can't hoard it all for yourself. Please pay attention when reading answers.